# How to solve exercise 2.2.12 in Ronald Brown's Topology and Groupoids

Tags: general-topology

The exercise is:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\vartriangleleft$ a relation on subsets of $X$ such that

> 1. $\varnothing \vartriangleleft \varnothing, X\vartriangleleft X$
> 2. $A\subset A', A'\vartriangleleft B', B'\subset B$ implies $A\vartriangleleft B$
> 3. $A\vartriangleleft B$ implies $A\subset B$
> 4. $A\vartriangleleft B, A'\vartriangleleft B'$ implies $A\cap A'\vartriangleleft B\cap B'$
> 5. $A_i\vartriangleleft B_i$ forall $i\in I$ implies $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\vartriangleleft \bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$

For each $x\in X, A\subseteq X$ define $A$ to be a neighbood of $x$ in $X$ if and only if $\{x\}\vartriangleleft A$. Prove that these neighbourhoods define a topology on $X$ for which $A\vartriangleleft B\iff A\subset \text{Int}\ B$ where $\text{Int}\ B=\{a\in A:\{a\}\vartriangleleft A\}$ .

For the four axioms of neighbourhoods

> 1. If $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ (i.e., $N \in N(x)$), then $x \in N$. In other words, each point belongs to every one of its neighbourhoods.
> 2. If $N$ is a subset of $X$ and contains a neighbourhood of $x$, then $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. I.e., every superset of a neighbourhood of a
>    point $x$ in $X$ is again a neighbourhood of $x$.
> 3. The intersection of two neighbourhoods of $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.
> 4. Any neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ contains a neighbourhood $M$ of $x$ such that $N$ is a neighbourhood of each point of $M$.

axioms 1, 2, 3 are easily to prove but I can't prove 4.

I can't prove $\{x\}\vartriangleleft A\implies \{x\}\vartriangleleft \bigcup_{a\vartriangleleft A}a$. I had tried to make a proof by contradiction but I had no idea about proving axiom 4 is false implies $A\in\{a\subset A:\{x\}\not\vartriangleleft a\}$ .

Comment: Try with $\operatorname{Int} N$ as defined above playing the role of $M$ in 4.

Comment: But I have no idea about proving $\{x\}\vartriangleleft A\implies \{x\}\vartriangleleft \bigcup_{a\vartriangleleft A}a$ as I have said in the discription